# Bigquery job-id - does it have TTL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of job-ids in BigQuery.

Suppose I registered a job-id into the big query (query, load...).

How much time it exists in the system?
Does it have a TTL?
Is it guaranteed it is unique forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is what i think is true:

- jobID is guaranteed to be unique within given project
  I just checked and confirming that jobIds I had in early 2014 are still somehow in the system, because I was not able to issue new jobId with those Ids
- while JobIds most likely stored in some or another way in BigQuery for "long" time, the project's complete job history availability is only guaranteed for jobs created in the past six months

*Of course would be great if someone from BigQuery Team can confirm or clarify this*

Comment: Thanks.
That is my understanding too.
Still would like it to be confirmed by the BQ team.